# RestTemplate with Query params

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using org.springframework.web.client.resttemplate
and I need to pass query params to my GET request.

Does anyone have any example of this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If you are putting variables in the request you are sending then it would be POST, I've answered that below.

Comment: @Jim it is perefectly sensible to send url parameters in a get request, why wouldn;t it be - thats what they are for

Comment: @NimChimpsky to clarify, query params I think is ambiguous and perhaps so is my comment. I agree that having parameters in the URL is acceptable, but not in the body of the HTML request.

Comment: ... and here's why http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/106261

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass them as part of the url string. Spring will do the rest, shown below are two types of parameter - an uri parameter and a request parameter:

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings?example=stack",String.class,"42");
```

[Docs here.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate)

Comment: Thanks for the help. there is an issue though when one of your uri paramter is pointing a json, for example: ?{searchKey}={searchValue}&page={page}&start={start}&limit={limit}&sort=[{property:\"{propertyValue}\",\"direction\":\"{direction}\"}]"

Comment: @Nir pass the json as one string and use jackson/gson to convert into a pojo server side

Comment: Thanks @NumChimpsky -> Do you have an example of this implementation?

Answer (score 3):

While making a request to a RESTful server, it requires in many a cases to send query parameters, request body (in case of `POST` and `PUT` request methods), as well as headers in the request to the server.

In such cases, the URI string can be built using [UriComponentsBuilder.build()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#build--), encoded using [UriComponents.encode()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html#encode--) (useful when you want to send JSON  or anything that has symbols `{` and `}` as part of the params), and sent using [RestTemplate.exchange()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-) like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> requestRestServerWithGetMethod()
{
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders); // requestHeaders is of HttpHeaders type
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rawValidUrl) // rawValidURl = http://example.com/hotels
            .queryParams(
                    (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>) allRequestParams); // The allRequestParams must have been built for all the query params
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode(); // encode() is to ensure that characters like {, }, are preserved and not encoded. Skip if not needed.
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,
            entity, String.class);
    return responseEntity;
}

public ResponseEntity<String> requestRestServerWithPostMethod()
{
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, requestHeaders); // requestBody is of string type and requestHeaders is of type HttpHeaders
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rawValidUrl) // rawValidURl = http://example.com/hotels
            .queryParams(
                    (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>) allRequestParams); // The allRequestParams must have been built for all the query params
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode(); // encode() is to ensure that characters like {, }, are preserved and not encoded. Skip if not needed.
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,
            entity, String.class);
    return responseEntity;
}
```